# Executing RSpec test in parallel using webdriver and Grid2

Tags: ruby, rspec, parallel-processing, webdriver

- GUI Automation Tool: Webdriver
- Parallel execution : Selenium Grid 2
- Scripting language : Ruby
- BDD Tool : Rspec

**My Test Looks like:**

```
def set_up
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote,:url => "http://localhost:4444",
    :desired_capabilities => :firefox)
end

def clean_up
  @driver.quit
end

it "test_direct_log_in" do
  @log_in_page = Page.new(@driver).go_to_log_in_Page
  @log_in_page.login("apple@gmail.com","password")
  Assert.new(@driver).verify_text_present("My Dashboard")
end

it "test_direct_log_in" do
  @log_in_page = Page.new(@driver).go_to_log_in_Page
  @log_in_page.login("banana@gmail.com","password")
  Assert.new(@driver).verify_text_present("My Dashboard")
end
```

Steps :

- Launch hub using java -jar selenium-server-staalone-2.3.0.jar -role hub
- Assigned node to the hub using java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxsession=20 -port 5555

I am able to execute test sequentially.. 
The real issue is I am not able to execute test in parallel...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: two things - The server name used to start the hub is not the same as the node, i would recommend running the same version for both the node and hub (version 21 is the latest stable version). And second, can you tell me how are u running two tests parallely?

Comment: Thanks ton for quick reply.      
                                                                     
First one was a copy paste mistake... I am using same server for both         
  
Second, Actually thats what I want to figure out that how can I run test parallely.. I understand that  some other tool should be used to execute tests in parallel. sthing like testng when tests are in java. Came across deep test while googling but not sure how to use it.

Comment: just try running the same selenium test script form two separate terminal tabs, based on your current configuration two windows should open up, and effectively run in parallel

Comment: I have two test files... apple_spec.rb(2 test) and banana_spec.rb (6)  
     
Executed them via two terminals still all of them were sequential...

Comment: So khsuhi, just to be clear, i hope you are not expecting that the 2 tests WITHIN the apple_spec.rb (and 6 tests within banana_spec.rb) to run parallely? All that Selenium grid will do is run apple_spec.rb and banana_spec.rb run parallely. I hope you see the difference.

Comment: yes I completely understand that part... if apple_spec.rb has one test and banana_spec.rb has one test... I want them to run in parallel

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: So khsuhi, just to be clear, i hope you are not expecting that the 2 tests WITHIN the apple_spec.rb (and 6 tests within banana_spec.rb) to run parallely? All that Selenium grid will do is run apple_spec.rb and banana_spec.rb run parallely. I hope you see the difference.            
     
**yes i read this comment**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the basis of what you have said,
let me clear out that selenium grid will not run multiple Unit Tests under one Test Suite because, if you have 4 tests under one test suite in one file(say apple.rb), 
Because when the test file is run, rspec will run them sequentially and eventually sel grid will run them sequentially.

Selenium grid though will run multiple requests hitting the hub at the same time.
So for example if you have two Terminal instances and you run apple.rb from both the instances, then Sel grid will run those tests parallely.

What you might be looking for, is to make Rspec to run the individual tests in parallel.

This could help https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

Comment: Thanks perlnewbie... yes while running same test at two terminal instances I am able to rum them in parallel .... Thanks for clearing my head and my thoughts process......... appreciated..

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, please mark my answer as the solution